# HTTP(S) Regional traffic route to specific resource - Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

Regions -

- UK
- USA
- Italy
- Singapore
- Australia

I have specific version of the site for each region and need to be deployed in different regions.

My Questions is -
I need to route rest of the traffic to a default region, is there any way to do this ?

I just set up HTTP external Load Balancer and it does the job only the issue is that default routing scenario.

Comment: What is your routing condition?

Comment: when coming from above regions, traffic will route to their near by locations as said above. i just need to add a default location to route other traffic

Comment: You mean you rely on the IP origin, right?

Comment: Yes indeed - 5 countries have specific pages and for the rest a default page

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't this type of loadbalancing on Google Cloud. You need to implement your own routing layer, to get the IP of the client, resolve the location and forward the request to the correct backend

Comment: Indeed yes. I did the routing with HTTP(S) loadbalancer and a srcipt. Thanks evryone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the routing with HTTP(S) loadbalancer and a script. Thanks everyone.